# Fitnesse define own table

Tags: java, slim, fitnesse

I´m using Fitnesse for database insert. The actual situation is: I create a new table in fitnesse like it is in the database and then I implement the Logic in a fixture in Java. But I want it to be generic. For example I want to use the same Fixture for different tables with difference database columns etc.
I saw dbfit has such a table, the "Insert" table. But dbfit is very slow compared to my actual use of fitnesse and my own Fixture for every dbtable.
But its much work to create a fixturecode for every new table. So is there an easy way to implement 1 fixture and every new dbtable in Fitnesse can use this Fixture to make database inserts?

thanks for help

Comment: I achieved something like this years ago using scenario tables and decision tables calling those scenarios. Unfortunately, the original code is not mine to share. The gist of how I did it is I used a class that had a number of script methods on it to build up a "stack" of elements to a command (we were SQL like but not SQL) and then a command that compiled the stack into a command and another to reset it. It was extremely generic to our application, though specific to our needs. I really should create an example version some day, but life gets in the way.

Comment: thanks I thought about something like that, too. But now I discovered a table called "TableTable" and you can create your own table with it. I think its very flexible. The problem with this is I cant find any documentation for this table. There is only one example with a Bowling table and how it was implemented in java. But there are no explanation for keywords like "pass" which colors a cell green. Or I need to show an exception in a specific Row like decision tables use it too. Is there a doc how to use the TableTable or how to throw Exception to a specific line?

Comment: TableTable works, but I've never liked to use it. You have to handle everything yourself and I think the documentation lacks because so few folks have really mastered it. It's been almost eight years since I tried. Myself, I'd use script tables any day over it. But. your milage may vary. Try also in the fitnesse yahoo group, might get help there.

Comment: ok thanks I wiil try it there!